# rich:tooltip displays empty tooltip where no field validation error

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I am using rich:tooltip to display the validation error messages. This works fine for fields where this is a field validation error but for fields where there is no field validation error an empty tooltip is displayed on mousemove. Here is how i am using it

```
<rich:tooltip target="field1" layout="block" showDelay="500">
  <rich:message for="field1" />
</rich:tooltip>
```

There is a possibility to control the render behavior of the tooltip using rendered attribute but i don't know how can i check on my page whether there exists a validation error message for a certain field or not.

Please give me some hint or idea about how to get rid of these empty tooltips.

Comment: Using tooltips for this seems a bit counter-intuitive. Shouldn't the user be informed about the validation error without having to mouse over the element to trigger the tooltip?

Comment: The problem is i have a very complex dynamically generated form view and it would cause design problems if i display the messages adjacent to input fields. That's why i used the Css approach to mark error fields with Red Rectangles and mouse move on them would display error detail as tooltip.

Comment: The `FacesContext` only gives you an iterator of all messages for a given clientId - a `Map` would have been great for your purpose. TBO, I would work with a traditional`<h:message` for every field and via JavaScript parse the document for field-messages and render the tooltip manually. Also via Javascript you can parse for empty tooltip boxes and remove them at the end...

Comment: How can i get the component client id of the input field? richt:tooltip and h:message are defined outside the h:inputText fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell if the message is rendered via Javascript.

#### Empty message

```
<span class="rf-msg " id="menuForm:j_idt12"></span>
```

#### Generated message

```
<span class="rf-msg " id="menuForm:j_idt12">
    <span class="rf-msg-err" id="menuForm:j_idt12:menuForm:error">
        <span class="rf-msg-sum">summary …</span>
        <span class="rf-msg-det">detail …</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}

<rich:tootltip styleClass="hidden">
    <rich:message … />
</rich:tooltip>

<rich:jQuery query="removeClass('hidden')" selector=".rf-tt:has(.rf-msg-err)" id="unhide" />
```

This will remove the hidden class from all tooltips where the message isn't empty. You will need to rerender it when you do the validation for it to work.